# How to prevent a value from changing every time a property is accessed

Tags: javascript

I need to make a constructor function that creates objects containing an Id property which value is an output of a function.

```
function rand(min, max) {
 return Math.ceil((max - min + 1) * Math.random()) + min - 1;
}

function generateId() {
  return Array(4).fill(1).map(value => rand(1000, 9999)).join('-');
}

class LoyaltyCard {
  constructor(name){
      this.name = name;
      this.id = generateId()
    }
}

var n = new LoyaltyCard('nnn')
```

When I assign a value to Id property like this, it changes every time the property is accessed. How can I set a ‘permanent’ value?

Comment: What do you mean? Every time you access `n.id` [it's always the same](http://jsbin.com/qonakacedu/1/edit?js,console). There is no issue here.

Comment: Doesn't look like it changes:  https://jsfiddle.net/s17xygf6/  What's the actual problem?

Comment: Thank you, guys! Now I see it's ok! We are supposed to use repl.it for our homeworks https://repl.it/GLtf/37 and every time i wrote console.log(n) and pressed run I saw the same object with different id... now i see it's because repl.it implements the code every time from the very beginning...